# NSForegroundColorAttributeName not working for UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, core-text

I have a problem changing substring color using "NSForegroundColorAttributeName". I'm confused since other attributes for the same substring are being applied(underline).

Also tried to use deprecated attribute "UITextAttributeTextColor" and other suggested attribute "kCTForegroundColorAttributeName" and got the same effect.

I'm compiling for iOS 7.

[image]

```
    NSString *freeText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@)", self.me.activity.text];

    int lblMaxWidth = arrImgView.origin.x - WPRConstraints.BorderOffset;
    int lblMaxHeight = self.activityView.size.height - WPRConstraints.BorderOffset * 2;

    RevUILabel *addActivityLbl = [[RevUILabel alloc] initWithFontNameMultiLine:[WPRFonts LattoBold]
                                                                          size:16
                                                                 sizeConstrain:CGSizeMake(lblMaxWidth,lblMaxHeight)];

    addActivityLbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", Translate(self.me.activity.activityKey), freeText] ;
    addActivityLbl.textColor = BlackColor;

    NSMutableAttributedString *str = [addActivityLbl.attributedText mutableCopy];



    [str addAttribute:NSUnderlineColorAttributeName  value:[UIColor redColor] range:[addActivityLbl.text rangeOfString:freeText]];
    [str addAttribute:NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName  value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:1] range:[addActivityLbl.text rangeOfString:freeText]];

    [str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                        value:[UIColor redColor]
                range:[addActivityLbl.text rangeOfString:freeText]];


    addActivityLbl.attributedText = str;


    addActivityLbl.frame = CGRectMake(WPRConstraints.BorderOffset,
                                      WPRConstraints.BorderOffset,
                                      addActivityLbl.size.width,
                                      addActivityLbl.size.height);
    [self.activityView addSubview:addActivityLbl];
```

Comment: Have you tried to pass a CGColor instead UIColor?

Comment: Yes I did with kCTForegroundColorAttributeName attribute

Comment: Sorry again, could comment the other attributes and update me with the results?

Comment: Please look in to the code I posted and the screenshot.

Comment: Does that label changes the text color elsewhere?

Comment: The only place is in code I posted before applying attributes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is this line:
`NSMutableAttributedString *str = [addActivityLbl.attributedText mutableCopy];`

I don't know the previous lines of your code, but it might be the case that `addActivityLbl.attributedText` is empty.

Secondly, using `NSAttributedString` with `UILabel` is not as reliable as using it with `UITextView`. The `attributedText` of a `UILabel` does inherit the attributes from the `text` of `UILabel` if the attributes are not explicitly provided.

Your `addActivityLbl.textColor` is black. And you still have not set your `addActivityLbl.attributedText ForegroundColorAttribute`. This means that your `addActivityLbl.attributedText` will inherit the BlackColor from your `addActivityLbl.textColor`.

This line will not work as expected; because you still have not set your `addActivityLbl.attributedText`. `freeText` has no range yet.

`[str addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                        value:[UIColor redColor]
                range:[addActivityLbl.text rangeOfString:freeText]];`

The underlyning works because underlyning is not a property of `addActivityLbl.text` (not inherited by attributedText).

I recommend you to use `UITextView` instead (which is safer). An other option is to set your `label.attributedText`, before referencing to some range of it.

Comment: I've tried to set attributed text before anything else and got very strange behaviour - dots instead of letters. Anyway, the only thing that works for me as expected is using UITextView instead of UILabel. I'm not that happy to use this workaround since I still do not understand root case of the problem. If I won't figure it out during next few days, I'll accept this answer.

Comment: I don't know what `RevUILabel` is. I googled it and couldn't find anything (but a 2 SO questions). Is it a subclass of `UIView`?

Comment: No. It is just UILabel extention

Comment: Using UITextView is the only solution I found so far.

Answer (score 11):

Make sure you're not setting some color on `textColor` property of `UILabel` *after* you've set the `attributedText`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem trying to set the color of the attributed title of a UIButton.  I was applying other attributes like underline and they worked, but the NSForegroundColorAttributeName attribute had absolutely no effect.

After pulling my hair out and questioning my own sanity, I eventually discovered that my problem was that in the storyboard, my button was set to be a `System` button:

[image]

And it needed to be `Custom`:

[image]

After changing that one setting in storyboard I was able to set NSForegroundColorAttributeName with expected, sane behavior.

I hope this helps someone!