# Different styles for links in a UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I want my UITextView includes plain text, links, phone numbers and other `UIDataDetectorTypes`. For instance, plain text - black color, links - blue color with underline, hashtags - green color. So, I parse text and add links to hashtags:

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hashtag://%@", hashtag] range:range];
```

Other links are detected by default, if `dataDetectorTypes` set to `UIDataDetectorTypeAll`. But how to change link style for hashtags?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the official Twitter library for tracking hashtags called [twitter text](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-text/tree/master/objc) along with [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/TTTAttributedLabel/TTTAttributedLabel).

Hashtags have special conditions, these could be more than alphanumeric characters preceded by #.

The twitter-text library will automatically find the ranges of hashtags for you then you should be able to format it with TTTAttributedLabel.

Here is a sample implementation of both libraries together.

```
- (void)scanForHashtag:(NSArray *)hashtags fromLabel:(id)sender
{
    TTTAttributedLabel *label = (TTTAttributedLabel *)sender;

    for (TwitterTextEntity *entity in hashtags) {
        UIFont *boldSystemFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12];
        CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)boldSystemFont.fontName, boldSystemFont.pointSize, NULL);
        NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName,(id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName,(NSString *)kCTFontAttributeName, nil];
        UIColor *hashtagColor;
        hashtagColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        NSArray *objects = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:hashtagColor,[NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleNone],(__bridge id)font, nil];
        NSDictionary *linkAttributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
        label.linkAttributes = linkAttributes;

        NSString *hashtag = [label.text substringWithRange:entity.range];

        if (entity.type == 2) { //Hashtag
            [label addLinkToPhoneNumber:hashtag withRange:entity.range];
        } else if (entity.type == 0) { //URL
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[label.text substringWithRange:entity.range]];
            [label addLinkToURL:url withRange:entity.range];
        }
    }
}

- (void)attributedLabel:(TTTAttributedLabel *)label didSelectLinkWithPhoneNumber:(NSString *)phoneNumber
{

    //Do whatever you need when the hashtag is tapped.
}

[self scanForHashtag:[TwitterText hashtagsInText:@"The text that contains the tweet with hashtags." checkingURLOverlap:NO] fromLabel:yourLabel]; //yourLabel is the label that contains the text so it would be formatted.
```

**EDIT FOR UITextView**

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                   value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                   range:entity.range];
```

Comment: Thanks, I've checked this. But is that possible with UITextView not UILabel?

Comment: Yes that is possible. The main point of my answer is about Twitter's official library that will help you detect hashtags. Once you detect them finding a solution to style the hashtags on your UITextView would be easier than having to find a solution for tracking hashtags.

Comment: Searching for hashtags is solved by regular expression w/o any library. The main problem now is that `linkTextAttributes` of `UITextView` override all my custom attributes in attributed string, if it's contain `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes it can be solved by regular expressions. However how many regular expressions can be suggested to be used for tracking hashtags. My solution is suggesting to use a more uniform/standard solution for tracking hashtags, one that follows Twitter.

Comment: For using it on a UITextView you can follow the logic of detecting the range of the hashtags and applying the styles into those range.

Comment: I did this. My attributes is not applied. Looks like `linkTextAttributes` is more preferable.

Comment: See my edit for implementation with a UITextView. After getting each range of TwitterEntity hashtags, set that range to the NSMutableAttributedString.

Comment: Actually `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` is changing, but `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` is not.

Comment: Take a look at this for NSForegroundColorAttributeName  http://stackoverflow.com/a/28525979/656718

Comment: Actually I override `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find **hashtags** ranges and than add special attributes for them.
For example.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"YOUR HASHTAG PATTERN" options:0 error:&error];
if (!error) {
    [regex enumerateMatchesInString:messageText options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, messageText.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop) {
        [mutableAttributedString addAttributes:@{
                                               NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontLinkMessageCell],
                                               (__bridge NSString*) kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor colorLinkOutCell],
                                               NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone),
                                               } range:result.range];
    }];
}
```

Comment: The problem is property `linkTextAttributes` of `UITextView` override all my custom attributes in attributed string, if it's contain `NSLinkAttributeName` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{};
self.textView.textStorage.delegate = self;

- (void) textStorage: (NSTextStorage*) textStorage didProcessEditing: (NSTextStorageEditActions) editedMask range: (NSRange) editedRange changeInLength: (NSInteger) delta
{
    [textStorage enumerateAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName
                            inRange: editedRange
                            options: 0
                         usingBlock: ^(id value, NSRange range, BOOL* stop)
                         {
                             if (value)
                             {
                                 [textStorage addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName
                                                     value: [UIColor redColor]
                                                     range: range];
                             }
                         }];
}
```